# Is this blow-up a line bundle over the projective line

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, vector-bundles, schemes, blow-ups

Let $R$ be the ring $\mathbb{C}[a,b,c,d]/(ac-b^2,bd-c^2,ad-bc)$. Let $I$ be the ideal of $R$ generated by $a,d$. Let $X=\operatorname{Spec}(R)$ and $\tilde{X}$ be the blow-up of the affine scheme $X$ along the ideal $I$.
Is this blow-up a line bundle over the projective line over the complex numbers? Why?
I used Macaulay2 to determine that the sequence $a,d$ in the ring $R$ is regular.
And there is a theorem that says the blow-up algebra of $R$ with respect to the ideal $I$ is isomorphic to the symmetric algebra of $I$ over $R$ in this case.
But I don't know how such information might be helpful in answering my questions.
Thank you very much for your kind help in advance.

Comment: $X$ is the cone over the twisted cubic (image of Veronese embedding $\mathbb{P}^1\to\mathbb{P}^3$.

Comment: Thanks for your information. Could you provide some additional insights into this problem? Thank you very much.

Comment: Do you have any reason to believe the blowup is a line bundle over the projective line? Have you at least checked it is smooth?

Comment: Thank you very much for your kind questions. I don’t have any concrete reason to believe that the blow-up is a line bundle over the projective line. I believe it is smooth, since the ideal I is generated by a regular sequence.

Comment: Regularity is definitely not enough: e.g., if you blowup the affine plane along the ideal $(x,y^2)$ the result is singular.

Comment: Thank you very much for your correction and counterexample. Could you provide some additional insights into this problem? Thank you very much.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: I was thinking that the blow-up might be smooth and hence, might be a line bundle over $\mathbb{P}^1$. And I would like to ask whether the blow-up is indeed a line bundle over the projective line. The exceptional divisor in this case is $\mathbb{P}^1$, and the center of the blow-up is the only closed singular point of $X$. Thank you very much for your kind help.

Comment: So, it is a good idea to start with checking smoothness. You can easily do it in affine charts.

Comment: Thank you very much for your kind advice.